# Sys.glob Directory Error

Tags: r, csv, syntax, directory, filepath

I'm attempting to load in multiple tripdata csv files from a directory that I defined in R as my current directory. I keep getting this dirmark error, and I'm sure that it's a syntax error in the way I'm defining my path.

data_dir <- '.'

Error in Sys.glob("%s/*-tripdata.csv", data_dir) : 
  invalid 'dirmark' argument

Comment: The command went through using the 'sprintf' function, but the variable I saved it to is still empty, returning character(0). I've checked both the location of my files and the regular expression syntax and both seem to be in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to use `sprintf` formats (i.e. `%s`) without actually calling `sprintf`

Something like

```
Sys.glob('./*-tripdata.csv')
```

should work

or

```
 Sys.glob(sprintf('%s/*-tripdata.csv',data_dir))
```